# Jenkins failing to execute SoapUI property transfer

Tags: rest, jenkins, groovy, soapui

So i have Groovy script which generate JWT token for me everytime i run my test suite. I'm using global variable for passing the token to request header. With my local setup its working perfectly fine, but when trying to run project via jenkins property transfer part fails and because of that whole JWT token generating fails. Any ideas why my solution is failing in jenkins? Thanks in advance! :)

```
def cmdArray2 = ["python", "C:/Users/SebastianAiraksinen/Testi/api.py"];
def process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray2).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
String fileContents = newFile('C:/Users/SebastianAiraksinen/Testi/token.txt')
```

[Image from my property transfer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUvU.png)

[Image from my global variable window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f3DI.png)

[Jenkins fail report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdu9w.png)

Comment: Hi there, please refrain from posting images of code. [Copy-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53812238/edit) your groovy script onto your question and [format it into a code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that ! Fixed that

Comment: Have you done anything to make your SoapUI able to execute Python, or is it able to do so out-of-the-box? You have hardcoded the output of the Python script to save the token file in your personal c:\Users\ folder. Is Jenkins running on the same machine (does that folder exist at all) and what user is it runing under (does that user have read/write access to that folder)? And once your solution is finished, are you sure that will work on another computer? And why do you have both a token variable referencing the output of your script AND another token variable referencing a global variable?

Comment: Hi Steen again. Im running local jenkins aswell atm ( for test ) so it has acces to that folder. And it is working when im setting the variable in one testcase with groovy script but i don't want to set that variable everytime in multiple testcases. So with global variable i can run the groovy script once and then just use global variable which holds value of my groovy script output. And in script i dont have token variable it is token.txt file and i read the output from that txt file.

Comment: Is SoapUI running under the same user when running under Jenkins? If not, it may be prevented from accessing the file. Besides, I'm confused by your global property Token. The value contains a variable. If your property transfer works properly, shouldn't the global Token property contain the value set by your Groovy Script?

Comment: I think its using the same user because i have run these same tests before with jenkins but in that case i hard coded the token. Yeah it should contain the value of my groovy script. And it is working when i run tests via SoapUI software.

Comment: You don't happen to locally have another global variable (fileContents), holding the file contents? And then when running in Jenkins, that global variable doesn't exist...?

Comment: Let me ask another way. Once you have run it locally, where you believe it is working correctly. What value does your global Token property have then?

Comment: After running the scripts it holds something like this "FL=12mdfe.rwer32r" so the token. It doesen't show it like ${#filecontents} anymore, but it changes everytime i run it --> It suppose to do this because every run generates new token.

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out ! Solution was that i had to mark "Add settings" from Test runner. That adds global settings to command line.

Comment: This just dawned on me too. The issue is using global properties. These are NOT saved in your current SoapUI project, but are kept elsewhere by the current SoapUI installation. If/when SoapUI is executed in Jenkins, then the Global properties are not set. Thus your property transfer fails, unless you set it to create any missing properties during test run.

Comment: As this is your obvious solution, you should accept your own answer to close the question.

Comment: Yeah ofc thanks for that tip. Im new to using Stackoverflow.